# css grid under 450px screen width does not center

Tags: html, css

so I need someone to proof my code because I think it might be missing a div or something more.

basically one section of the html code works fine on big screens such as desktop tablets but when on the mobile screen such under 450px width it does not centre im just wondering what the cause is.

i've have used css grid and tried to fix it

the section is under:

```
<div class="main-rules">
        <div class="section-rules">
            <h2 class="rules-heading">Rules/Guidelines</h2>
            <div class="rules">
```

here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kpwsbfc2/

and here is the real site:

http://tawedgame.epizy.com/index.php

Comment: have you tries **word-wrap** property? because i see the content is overflowing on that section may be because of large numbers of words  it is overflowing to right side which seems not in center.

Comment: Please create a minimal, reproducable example of your problem, we are not here to debug your whole site.

Comment: and just curious, have you checked it in real device? i can see you're text size isn't responsive as well so may be it keeps the desktop text size to display in responsive tool.

try to change text size

Comment: yep checked in on real devices it had a slight left margin of space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add

```
@media(max-width:450px){
    h2.rules-heading {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
    .player-value {
        width: 280px;
    }
    .player-value button {
        width: 113px;
    }
    .player-value span {
        margin: 0 -48px;
    }
}
```

Comment: but could u please explain what word-break even does?

Comment: Please check with https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/